# I have both users and clients model where the client belongs to users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

my index action in clients controller looks like this

def index

```
@user = Users.find_by(params[:users_id])

@clients = @user.clients.find_by(first_name :params[:first_name])
```

end

but i keep getting error  "uninitialized constant Users::Client"

Comment: Can you post your users and client models?

Comment: i can't seem to open the client/index page because of this error,please guys i really need help here my client model looks like thisclass Clients < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users

Comment: The answer below is correct it should be `User.find_by` instead of `Users`

Comment: but i called my model users instead of user,could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes the model should be user and the able should be users like Kushal has said, same with clients

Comment: i get this error when i edit Users to User...                                    uninitialized constant ClientsController::User

Comment: Have you restarted the server and renamed the users.rb to user.rb

Comment: i will have to drop the model and just migrate another with the right syntax this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo. it should be a 'User' not 'Users'. always model name should be a singular and table name should be plural in rails.

Comment: so you are saying my app will not work unless i rename model users to user?     is rails that sensitive and strict?

Comment: you just have to correct a typo in query you are trying to execute.
and for your question, here is an answer [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions)

Comment: but having changed the model name clients to client  and users to user i get the error     "SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
my controller looks like this                                                                 ' def create
  user = User.new(params_attr)
   if user.save
    UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver
     session[:confirm_email]="true"
           redirect_to account_confirmation_path(user.company_name)
    
   else 
    
    render 'index'
    
    end

 end